# Breadcrumbs in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, breadcrumbs

I want to use [Angular's breadcrumb capability](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/services/breadcrumbs.js). I added this javascript file to my services folder.

I added a div to my header.html file to call the javascript. According to Angular, the div should look like this:

```
<div>
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.getAll()">
      <span class="divider">/</span>
      <ng-switch on="$last">
        <span ng-switch-when="true">{{breadcrumb.name}}</span>
        <span ng-switch-default><a href="{{breadcrumb.path}}">{{breadcrumb.name}}</a></span>
       </ng-switch>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The div is being created, and when I inspect it I see
`<!-- ngRepeat: breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.getAll() -->`

But no breadcrumbs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

It's not enough to just add the HTML to your header template file. Make sure you've also completed the following:

1. Include `breadcrumbs.js` in your main HTML template (usually index.html):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="your-project-folder/services/breadcrumbs.js"></script>
   ```
2. Include `services.breadcrumbs` as a module dependency for your main app:

   ```
   angular.module('myMainApp', ['services.breadcrumbs']);
   ```
3. Finally, make sure you actually inject the `breadcrumbs` service into your controller, and then attach it to $scope:

   ```
   angular.module('myMainApp').controller('FooBarCtrl', function($scope, breadcrumbs) {
       $scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;

       // ... other controller logic ...
   });
   ```

You can see the implementation of Steps 2 and 3 in the angular-app project [in the app.js file](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/5d8f8d0af623b62dd75baae291bc530525041d1a/client/src/app/app.js) (refer to lines 6, 60, and 62).